# heap memory recommended for jenkins with docker (JAVA_OPTS)

Tags: java, jenkins, heap-memory, ram

What should be minimum and maximum recommended size for heap memory in JENKINS as per ram size ?

**I want to know the minimum and maximum % percentage of RAM which can be use for HEAP**

While starting jenkins server on Docker container, generally pass JAVA_OPTS parameter for heap memory allocation. There parameters are given below,
Use -Xmx to specify the maximum heap size 
Use -Xms to specify the initial Java heap size 
Use -Xss to set the Java thread stack size

The example command would be:

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --env JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -Xms512m  Dhudson.footerURL=http://mycompany.com jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Comment: Those parameters highly depend on your personal usage of the Jenkins server and can't be provided without examining the actual load. It's better to start with some reasonable values and increase/decrease if needed. Also, you should insert space between params  JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Xms512m". Xmx better to set larger than Xms. Start with 512/1024m, watch logs and tune this params

Comment: which java version is being used?, based on the version we can use Container flag `UseContainerSupport`

Comment: @AlexeySviridov Thanks for quick response. Let me change my question in different way. I want to know the minimum and maximum % percentage of RAM which can be use for HEAP

Comment: @dkb I am not concern about java image. But want to know the how much heap % can be used from RAM

Comment: @MaheshWaikar It still depends. Too many things can affect available memory - system settings (swap, caches, etc), number of other running processes. By default, JAVA uses half of the available memory for the Xmx param, which is reasonable from my point of view. Technically, you can set it to zero or to 100 percent, but it won't work. You can play with that param and see the result. If you set it to the wrong value (too high or too low) your process won't start at all, or crashed after some time.